# How to group different list elements including '_' into list without changing sequence order？

Tags: python

rawinput:

`lst = ['a_app','a_bla','a_cat','b','c','d_d1','d_xe','d_c','e_1','e_2','f']`

The elements in `lst` are strings

expected result:

`new_lst = [['a_app','a_bla','a_cat'],'b','c',['d_d1','d_xe','d_c'],['e_1','e_2'],'f']`

Any of element including `'_'` will be grouped into a list element but their starts will be grouped into different list if different such as `['a_app','a_bla','a_cat']`,  `['d_d1','d_xe','d_c']`.

Notice: The sequence of new list will not change just compressed strings including '_' into a list.

Comment: You can write a function to do this with the programming language python. Have you tried that? If so, please add your code to the question.

Comment: show first what you have tried ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ['a_app','a_bla','a_cat','b','c','d_d1','d_xe','d_c','e_1','e_2','f']
>>> [list(strs) for _,strs in groupby(lst, lambda s: s.split('_')[0])]
[['a_app', 'a_bla', 'a_cat'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d_d1', 'd_xe', 'd_c'], ['e_1', 'e_2'], ['f']]
```

Now that you wrote some code, here's a way to convert 1-element sublists to a string:

```
>>> new_list = [list(strs) for _,strs in groupby(lst, lambda s: s.split('_')[0])]
>>> [strs if len(strs) > 1 else strs[0] for strs in new_list]
[['a_app', 'a_bla', 'a_cat'], 'b', 'c', ['d_d1', 'd_xe', 'd_c'], ['e_1', 'e_2'], 'f']
```

It might be easier to work with a list of lists than a list with mixed types (lists and strings), though.

Comment: Thanks, I will do like this based on your tips:lst = `['a_app','a_bla','a_cat','b','c','d_d1','d_xe','d_c','e_1','e_2','f']

imp = [list(strs) for _,strs in groupby(lst, lambda s: s.split('_')[0])]

new_lst = []
for i in imp:
    if len(i)==1:
        new_lst.append(''.join(i))
    else:
        new_lst.append(i)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with following code:

```
lst = ['a_app','a_bla','a_cat','b','c','d_d1','d_xe','d_c','e_1','e_2',f]
new_lst = []
tmp = [] # This will be used to group elements like 'a_app' and 'a_bla'.

for el in lst:
    # If _ is not in string, we add the string directly to new_lst
    # and continue with next string.
    if '_' not in el:
        new_lst.append(el)
        continue

    # If tmp is empty, we just add the current string. It obviously
    # contains _, otherwise we wouldn't get there (above if clause).
    if tmp == []:
        tmp.append(el)
        continue

    # Compare first letter of current string with the first letter of
    # first string in tmp. If it is the same, add current string to tmp.
    if el[0] == tmp[0][0]:
        tmp.append(el)

    # If it is not the same, that means that tmp is ready to be appended
    # new_lst. We must also reset the tmp.
    else:
        new_lst.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
```